# ConsoleHandler logs infos to console although log level is warning

Tags: java, logging

In my project i use some different loggers, that all have a FileHandler and a ConsoleHandler attached. I create those loggers with the following class:

```
public class Logging {

static {
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "properties/logging.properties");
    try {
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to create a new logger using java.util.logging.
 * @param name The name of the logger.
 * @param logLevelFile The log level for writing into the log file.
 * @param logLevelConsole The log level for writing on the console.
 * @param logToFile True, if file logging shall be active.
 * @param logToConsole True, if console logging shall be active.
 * @return The new logger instance.
 */
public static Logger createLogger(String name, Level logLevelFile, Level logLevelConsole, boolean logToFile, boolean logToConsole) {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
    logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

    if (logToFile) {
        final Handler fileHandler;
        try {

            fileHandler = new FileHandler("log/" + name + ".log");
            fileHandler.setLevel(logLevelFile);
            logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

            // close file handler, so that *.lck files will be deleted by
            // JVM
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fileHandler.close();
                }
            }));

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (logToConsole) {

        // remove existing console handlers
        Handler[] handlers = logger.getHandlers();
        for (Handler handler : handlers) {
            if (handler.getClass() == ConsoleHandler.class)
                logger.removeHandler(handler);
        }

        Handler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consoleHandler.setLevel(logLevelConsole);

        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);

    }

    return logger;

}

}
```

As you can see, each logger gets a boolean, whether it should log into a file and into the console. Dependent on that it is possible to set, which level shall be logged into console or file.

My logging.properties look like that:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter  = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter     = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format    = [%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY-%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS] [%2$s] %4$s: %5$s %n

# approximate amount of bytes to write to a log file, before rotating to a new file
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 500000

# number of log files to use in the log file rotation
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 0

# whether or not the FileHandler should append to an existing file or not (true or false)
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append = false
```

I initialize my loggers as follows:

```
Logging.createLogger(Properties.getGeneralLoggerName(), Level.INFO, Level.INFO, true, true);
Logging.createLogger(Properties.getBluetoothLoggerName(), Level.INFO, Level.INFO, true, true);
Logging.createLogger(Properties.getStrategicProcessesLoggerName(), Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, true, true);
Logging.createLogger(Properties.getNetworkLoggerName(), Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, true, true);
Logging.createLogger(Properties.getGPIOLoggerName(), Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, true, true);
Logging.createLogger(Properties.getFatigueDetectionLoggerName(), Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, true, true);
Logging.createLogger(Properties.getGPSACCLoggerName(), Level.INFO, Level.WARNING, true, true);
```

The problem is, that for example the last logger does not log only warnings into the console, but also info logs. On my mac book this all works fine, but when I use this code on my embedded system (Odroid U3 with Ubuntu 14.04) it fails and the console outputs are massive. Instead of logging the outputs into the file, they are logged into the console.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code you are adding a shutdown hook to close your FileHandler to remove 'lck' files.  The reason you would have to do that is because you are [not holding a strong reference to your created logger](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6274920).  You must hold a strong refrence to your logger [otherwise your added handlers will not be closed on shutdown by the LogManager](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060132).

If your are letting your [logger get garbage collected](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6949710) then the next new instance of that logger is going to inherit the level settings from the parent logger and not the level set in your 'createLogger' method.

> Instead of logging the outputs into the file, they are logged into the console.

The FileHandler can throw exceptions.  Fix the cause of the exception.  The addShutdownHook method can also throw exceptions that are not trapped in your code.